# Plotting bar of year versus ratings

Tags: python

I could use some advice on how to solve my problem making a plot where year = X and ratings = Y.

Have created two lists called:

```
Ratings_sorted = []
Year = []
```

These lists have the len 250 both and an example from both are:

```
Ratings_sorted = ['8.3', '8.2', '8.2', '8.3', '8.5', '8.4', '8.2', '8.5', '8.2', '8.2', '8.1', '8.4', '8.2', '8.1', '8.4', '8.2', '8.6', '8.4', '8.6', '8.1', '8.1', '8.0', '8.3', '8.3',
Year = ['1921', '1925', '1926', '1927', '1931', '1931', '1934', '1936', '1939', '1939', '1939', '1940', '1940', '1940', '1941', '1941', '1942', '1944', '1946',
Ratings
```

So this is only a taste of my lists, which are 250 long.

Have tried to produce the bar plot with following code.

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

plt.bar(Year, sorted_ratings)
plt.suptitle('Ratings based on years', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Rating', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)  
plt.show()
```

When try to run it, i get an error:

cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Read something about my Ratings are not integers, then i tried the function map like this:

```
sorted_ratings2 = map(int, sorted_ratings)
```

Then i get the following error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.3'

Hope someone maybe knows what is wrong here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you have quotes around your numbers, that's why they're being read as strings. The 'map' method works, per @thecoder16's answer. Make sure that the lengths of the ratings and the years are the same - I was getting that error earlier when you posted the previous question.

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
sorted_ratings = ['8.3', '8.2', '8.2', '8.3', '8.5', '8.4', '8.2', '8.5', '8.2', '8.2']

Years = ['1921', '1925', '1926', '1927', '1931', '1931', '1934', '1936', '1939', '1939']

x_pos = np.arange(len(Years))

sorted_ratings2 = map(float, sorted_ratings)

plt.bar(x_pos, sorted_ratings2)
plt.suptitle('Ratings based on years', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(x_pos, Years) 
plt.ylabel('Rating', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: I done it and i get a bar plot now.. But, one thing, how do i get label years into the Axse? it says from 0 to 250, but it should show what years it is?

if i print x_pos it should a array from 0 to 250, but not the years?

Comment: it's the plt.xticks(x_pos, Years). x_pos tells it where to put the labels, and Years is the list of the labels.

Answer (score 2):

Your ratings are best represented by floating-point numbers, so `map(float, sorted_ratings)` should work. You may also want to look into the `datetime` library for your years.

Answer (score 1):

Your ratings are decimals, so you use floats. `map(float, sorted_ratings)` works. Here is a demo:

```
x = "3"
print int(x)#Just 3
y = "8.5"
print int(y) # Oh no! Integers can’t have decimal points…
```

That is Python 2.x. For Python 3.x your code would work fine, but all the numbers would be rounded.